# Getting SignalR code to run before handler code triggered during await invoke

Tags: javascript, signalr, signalr.client

Let's say I set up a JS SignalR connection to have a handler that responds to incoming messages from the server:

```
this.connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(this.hubUrl)
    .build();

this.connection.on("GameDataUpdatedV1", async (evt: GameDataUpdatedEvent) => {
    this.#handleGameDataUpdate(evt.updateData);
});

#handleGameDataUpdate = async (update: GameDataUpdate) => {
    console.log("Handler running...");
}
```

Now I await a SignalR call to the server:

```
try {
    console.log("About to invoke...");
    await this.connection.invoke("TestInvoke", { testData: 123 });
    console.log("Resumed from invoke.");
}
catch (err) {
    console.log("Error during invoke!");
    return;
}
```

The server sends `GameDataUpdatedV1` messages every 2 seconds, and the `TestInvoke` takes about 10 seconds to run.  What I get in the console is:

```
About to invoke...
Handler running...
Handler running...
Handler running...
Handler running...
Resumed from invoke.
```

I want the 'resumed from invoke' code to run *before* the handler calls, but it runs them before it runs the code that resumes after the invoke call has returned.  How can I get it to run in the order I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `invoke` awaits the response. You'd need to change to not await the `TestInvoke` command:

```
console.log("About to invoke...");
this.connection
    .invoke("TestInvoke", { testData: 123 })
    .then(() => {
       console.log("Invoke successfully completed");
    });
    .catch(() => {
       console.log("Error during invoke!");
    });

// runs immediately after `invoke` is called, not awaiting response
console.log("Resumed from invoke.");
```